# How we can give multiple id to input type?

Tags: javascript

```
html +="<td>"+vegetable[i].category+"</td>";
html +="<td>"+vegetable[i].name+"</td>";
html +="<td>"+vegetable[i].mrp+"</td>";
html +="<td>"+"<input id ='vegetable'"+i+" type=number min=0 max=10 value=0>"+"</td>";
```

Comment: What is your business requirement, what is the output you are trying to achieve, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Code formatting change

Answer (score 1):

No DOM element can have more than one `id`. If you give it more than one, subsequent ones will be ignored. `id`s must be unique and no two DOM elements can have the same `id`. Otherwise, `document.getElementById` will return the first element with the `id` that it finds.

If you want to style or select all the `input` elements that were created dynamically, consider giving it a class so you can get all of them using a query selector.

```
document.querySelector('input.myClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invert your string delimiters, from:

```
"<input id ='vegetable'"+i+" type=number"
```

to:

```
'<input id ="vegetable'+i+'" type=number'
```

In the first case the rendered id will be something like: <input id="vegetable" 1.....

Answer (score 0):

Change this line **`html +="<td>"+"<input id ='vegetable'"+i+" type=number min=0 max=10 value=0>"+"</td>";`** to **`html += "<td>"+"<input id ='vegetable"+i+"' type='number' min='0' max='10' value='0'>"+"</td>";`**
It was just the position of the marker. I think is gonna work fine.

Check [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kathru/mtrdfx7b/3/)